# Create MasterCard tokenization API

Tags: api, mastercard

I have a mobile app containing payment method via MasterCard. I have this tutorial:

https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/api.html?locale=en_US

I want to create Tokenization which contains customer's master detail, I have followed this tutorial part:

[https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Tokenization%3a Create or Update Token (with system-generated token).html?locale=en_US](https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/apiDocumentation/rest-json/version/latest/operation/Tokenization%3A%20Create%20or%20Update%20Token%20(with%20system-generated%20token).html?locale=en_US)

I tried with :

**POST** `https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/41/merchant/{{MyMerchantID}}/token`

**Params:**

```
{
"sourceOfFunds": {
"type": "CARD",
"provided": {
"card":{
"number": "5123450000000008",
"expiry": {
"month": "05",
"year": "17"
}
}
}
```

Note: The number is a  mastercard test number.

I am always get this error:

```
error   
cause   "INVALID_REQUEST"
explanation "Invalid credentials."
result  "ERROR"
```

I followed the params in second URL.
Can anyone help? Are the params correct or I missed something?

Comment: for which country you are using this?

Answer (score 2):

In your configuration file, you need to set the following:

`$configArray["merchantId"] = "[merchantId]";`

// API username in the format below where Merchant ID is the same as above

`$configArray["apiUsername"] = "merchant.[merchantId]";`

// API password which can be configured in Merchant Administration

`$configArray["password"] = "your api password";`

Setting the above parameters in the config file will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

First, you should ask you bank to enable the tokenization for your merchant account

POST
[https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/61/merchant/{{MyMerchantID}}/token](https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/rest/version/61/merchant/%7B%7BMyMerchantID%7D%7D/token)

you have to set `Authorization->Basic Auth`

Username : Your_MerchantID
Password : ApiPassword

Params:

```
{
  "session": {
    "id": "SESSION0002510583427E2239608H32"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "ap-gateway" with the real gateway provided for you. Your merchantID is not supported in test gateway.